# ERROR TypeError: this.dataSource.filter is not a function

Tags: angular

am using angular 6 to implement  Edit/ Add/ Delete Rows in Material Table with using Dialogs inline Row Operation but am getting the error datasource.filter is not a function when i press the update button i don't know whats the problem here and what am i missing.

**Here is my update-admin-info.component.ts***

````
```import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef   } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatTable} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../model/User.model'
import { DialogeditComponent } from '../dialogedit/dialogedit.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-admin-info',
  templateUrl: './update-admin-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-admin-info.component.css']
})
export class UpdateAdminInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email','college','department','action'];
   dataSource;
  users: User[];

  @ViewChild(MatTable,{static:true}) table: MatTable<any>;

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }


  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private userservice:UserService,private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userservice.getAdmins()
    .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
      this.users = users;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);

    });
  }

  editUser(action,obj)
{
  obj.action = action;
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogeditComponent,{
    width: '250px',
    data:obj

  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if(result.event == 'update')
    {
      this.updateRowData(result.data);
    }

  });

     this.cdr.detectChanges();
}

updateRowData(row_obj){
  this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((value,key)=>{
    if(value._id == row_obj.id){
      value.firstname = row_obj.firstname;
    }
    return true;
  });

 this.cdr.detectChanges();
 this.table.renderRows();
}


}```
````

**here is my Dialogedit.component.ts**

````
```import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { User } from '../model/User.model';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { UpdateinfoService } from '../services/updateinfo.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialogedit',
  templateUrl: './dialogedit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialogedit.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class DialogeditComponent implements OnInit {

  action:string;
  local_data:any;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogeditComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: User, public http: HttpClient, public updateinfo: UpdateinfoService, public router: Router, private userservice:UserService,private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {  console.log(data);
      this.local_data = {...data};
      this.action = this.local_data.action;}

  ngOnInit() {


  }
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close({event:'Cancel'});
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  onEdit() {
    this.dialogRef.close({event:this.action,data:this.local_data});
    this.userservice.selectedUser =this.local_data;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }


}```
````

**here is my Dialogedit.component.html**

````
```<h1 mat-dialog-title>Row Action :: <strong>{{action}}</strong></h1>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="action != 'Delete'; else elseTemplate">
          <input   matInput [(ngModel)]="local_data.firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input  matInput [(ngModel)]="local_data.lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()"  mat-flat-button color="warn">Cancel</button>
        <button  mat-button (click) = "onEdit(local_data)"  >{{action}}</button>
      </div>```
````

**The error am getting is in this line here `this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((value,key)=>{`**

Comment: Is `datasource` array?

Comment: this is becuase `dataSource` is *undefined* to fix it `dataSource :any[] = []`

Comment: ``dataSource`` is not an array but of type ``MatDataSource`` hence the error

Comment: how can i solve it brother @PareshLomate

Comment: how can i solve this bro @CruelEngine

Comment: @KyleMutta Have you tried: `dataSource :any[] = [];` or `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);`

Comment: instead of `this.dataSource.filter` use `this.dataSource.data.filter`

Comment: yes @PrashantPimpale but it still throws the error

Comment: where `applyFilter` method gets called?

Comment: @PareshLomate it worked brother but still my data cant be updated if anyone can help me with this how to implemenet inline editing on table using matDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gone through the code for `MatTableDataSource` and it has `get data()` which returns array of objects. So you should use `this.dataSource.data.filter` instead of `this.dataSource.filter`.

As per your second question goes,

> still my data cant be updated if anyone can help me with this how to implemenet inline editing on table using matDialog

that's a new thread, please open new question on SO.

Comment: could i get your email i want to implement that and its for my final year project am ready to pay for that assistance bro

Comment: There are many online forums like SO where you can get help. People are willing to help you. As far as paid assistance goes which is mostly doing project by someone else, IMHO please try to complete the project on your own. It will help you in long run. The shortcut might help you now but you might regret the decision later. Please take this as advice and not offence.

Answer (score 0):

is this.datasource.filter  is array?

you have this.datasource.filter and filter is also array method..

i think you rename it..

or!!

this.data.source may not be array

console.log everything